# Look up value corresponding to boolean

Tags: excel

I could not find any questions regarding this issue, which is:

I have a sheet with rows:companyname and columns:product. We indicate a company buys a product with either one or zero.

Example of row:

```
Apple 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

I want Excel to look up the prices for the products indicated by one and it should put the sum into column:total. I am having now having difficulties on how to deal with an array of values.

Do you guys have any tips? I looked up VLOOKUP and MATCH but could not find what I wanted.

Thank you!

Kevin

Comment: Is it possible to transpose the product list so that it's in a row? then you could just use a simple SUMPRODUCT or SUMIF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to use the SUMPRODUCT function, you will need the prices for your products to be across one row and in the same order as the columns indicated above. please see the screenshot for an example of it could work

[image: Example of SUMPRODUCT implementation]

Comment: To add to this: If looking at different values than 0 and 1 (even though it is indicated that this is the case here) one can use either SUMIF or SUMIFS for similar results.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do that, then to the best of knowledge it would need an array formula like this

```
=SUM(B2:H2*TRANSPOSE(J$2:J$8))
```

which has to be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

where the 1's and 0's are in B2:H2 and the product list prices in J2:J8.

[image]